# karma/jasmine to test an angular app, can't inject

Tags: karma-jasmine

I spent few hours on this issue and can't find what's wrong, I'm using karma/jasmine to create test in my angular app. I use, or at least try to use angular-mock to inject and test my controllers but I get this error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ENVProvider <- ENV
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/unpr?p0=ENVProvider%20%3C-%20ENV
```

in my test

```
describe('controllers', function(){
```

beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  var $controller;

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe('$scope.testMessage', function() {
    it('check the test message is ok', function() {
        //TODO
    });
});
```

});

So I suppose it's the inject call which cause the issue

here is my karma.conf.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(config) {
var configuration = {
autoWatch : true,

frameworks: ['jasmine'],

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  stripPrefix: 'src/',
  moduleName: 'hematiteFront'
},

browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

plugins : [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],

files: [
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'bower_components/angular/*.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/angular-materialize/js/*.js',
  'bower_components/angular-materialize/src/*.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

  'src/**/*.js'
],

logLevel: 'LOG_ERROR',

exclude: [
  'src/app/app.constants.js',
  'bower_components/**/index.js',
  'bower_components/**/*.min.js'
],


preprocessors: {
  'src/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
}
  };


  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Any idea or piece of advice would be more than wellcome

thanks

Comment: can you post the controller you are trying to test?